# Let $X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}$, for $n=2,3,...,$ be independent and identically distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}$, for $n=2,3,...,$ be independent and identically distributed  random variables with common distribution function. $F_{X}$ . Find a formula for the joint distribution $F_{Y,Z}$ for

$$Y=\max\{X_{1}, X_{2},...,X_{n}\} \quad \text{and} \quad Z=\min\{X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}\}$$

in terms of $F_{X}$.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the marginal distribution of the maximum and the minimum ?

Comment: As was already mentioned about another post by the same OP, with no answer from said OP: *In order to help you with homework, you need to show us what you've done so far*.

Comment: Please improve the title!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\begin{align*}
F_{Y, Z}(y, z)
&= \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y \ \text{and} \ Z \leq z)\\
&= \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) - \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y \ \text{and} \ Z > z)\\
&= \mathbb{P}(\forall i, \ X_i \leq y) - \mathbb{P}(\forall i, \ z < X_i \leq y)\\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=} \mathbb{P}(X \leq y)^{n} - \mathbb{P}(z < X \leq y)^{n}\\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=} F_X(y)^{n} - (F_X(y) - F_X(z))^{n},
\end{align*}$$
where we have used independence assumption at (1), and identical distribution assumption at (2).